# No privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

Tags: oracle-12c

I am creating to the user after create table, but not insert the data why?
Then display the message NO PRIVILEGES ON TABLESPACE 'USERS'

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is [`SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/segment-creation-on-demand-11gr2).

This feature of Oracle was introduced ~11gR2.  It allows large applications to `CREATE TABLE` for everything in the application without using disk space.  The application will use 0 bytes for the tables that the customer won't use. (eg they aren't licensed for the feature(s) that uses those tables)

This feature has the side-effect of allowing you to `CREATE TABLE` on a tablespace which you don't have a quota.

## to fix

Your `CREATE USER` needs to include a `QUOTA` clause in order to add data to that tablespace.  You could easily `ALTER USER` to add a quota.

There is also the over powering `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE` system privilege.  It grants the user `QUOTA UNLIMITED` on all tablespaces (including `SYSTEM` and `SYSAUX` -- which you shouldn't use).  This privilege seems to go against the security concept of "least privileges".  Use it sparingly.